# CSS not changing text color?

Tags: html, css, colors, tumblr, textcolor

I've looked around for answers to this question, and I haven't been able to find any. I'm trying to change the color of the text of my description. I have the following CSS:

```
.description {
position:fixed;
overflow:auto;
width:200px;
height:130px;
margin-left:115px;
margin-top:235px;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
opacity:1;
text-align:center;
font-family:'calibri';
font-size:10px;
color:{color:Title};
background-color:{color:border};
z-index:1;
}
```

And the corresponding `div` stuff (sorry, I'm not that good with the lingo yet.)

```
<div class="description">
{block:Description}<div class="text">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}</div>
```

Now, the border color is #8f8f8f and the title color is #ffffff at the moment. However, the text color is showing up as the border color instead of the title color. If I change the `background-color` to something else (for example, the background color), the text color stays #8f8f8f. I've also tried making a whole new thing dedicated to description color in the meta name section at the top, as well as changing it from `{color:Title}` to something like `{color:background}` or similar things to that.

What I would like to know is: why is the text color not showing up as the title color, and how can I fix this?

Thanks to anybody who helps.

Comment: which one you need to change color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck your code.
Your Meta Tag should look something like this:

```
 <meta name="color:title" content="#ffffff"/>
```

And then your CSS should be:

```
.description {
  position:fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  width:200px;
  height:130px;
  margin-left:115px;
  margin-top:235px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  opacity:1;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:'calibri';
  font-size:10px;
  color:{color:title};
  background-color:{color:border};
  z-index:1;
}
```

And then you have the text wrapped in another class named text. See yourself:

```
<div class="description">
 {block:Description}<div class="text">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
</div>
```

So Text that gets filled in with the {Description} variable will have the class "text" applied to it. That overwrites the styles from the "description" before that, because it follows it. So if there's a .text class in you CSS and there's "color: whatever" in this, that will overwrite your color from ".description" in this case.

So in your CSS there should also be:

```
.text {
      color:{color:title};
}
```

If you want all text inside an element with the class="text" to have that text color.
Element could be

```
<div class="text">XYZ</div>
```

for example.